# Styling a link based on class and its href content

Tags: html, css

And i want to create a css that is specific to this button only that has the `href="https://link.com/inst` link and is of class `btn btn-primary btn-block`.

the class `btn btn-primary btn-block` is a global bootstrap class therefore if i redefine the class only it will change any other button in the website.

```css
.btn .btn-primary .btn-block a[href^="https://link.com/inst"]{
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:22px;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://link.com/inst" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate Your Order</a>
```

I dont know how to incorporate this two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the class assignment for the `<a>` tag. Like this:

```
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-block[href^="https://link.com/inst"] {}
```

```css
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-block[href^="https://link.com/inst"] {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:22px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate Your Order</a>
<a href="https://link.com/inst" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate Your Order</a>
```

The second solution is to specify an attribute with classes in the css for the `<a>` tag. Like this:

```
a[href^="https://link.com/inst"][class^="btn btn-primary btn-block"] {}
```

```css
a[href^="https://link.com/inst"][class^="btn btn-primary btn-block"] {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:22px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate Your Order</a>
<a href="https://link.com/inst" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Calculate Your Order</a>
```